# Changing the icons used by Sumatra PDF reader

Tags: windows, icons, pdf-reader, sumatra-pdf

I like the simple design of Sumatra PDF reader, but the ugly icons it uses are ugly my question is how to replace them.

Specifically how do I replace:

[image]

The icons used in file explorer beside pdf files/files opened by Sumatra.

[image]

The icon used to represent Sumatra in the taskbar, all programs and so on.

**Notes**

- I am using the 64-bit windows version of Sumatra (Windows 10 ).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hack the executable (.exe) and find and replace the icons by
ones of the same size.

You could use a tool such as
[Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
or any one of its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/resource-hacker/).
An icon-painting tool might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I find the PDF icons in Microsoft Edge to be much better.

You could try configuring this with Nirsoft File Types Manager (using the string below) but that only works for administrator accounts. The easiest way I've found for standard accounts is to edit the registry directly. Use the string "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe,13" for:

- key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SumatraPDF.pdf\DefaultIcon`, default value
- key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SumatraPDF.pdf\shell\open`, `Icon` value